# Is there any way to skip Combo Chicken lessons?

Tags: guacamelee

I am really enjoying Guacamelee, but I have a bit of a problem with fine motor skills, so executing combos correctly is SUPER difficult for me sometimes.

Right now I seem to be stuck with Combo Chicken, trying to do a combo that is pretty impossible for me so far.

Is there any way for me to get past this without getting the combo correct? Or has my inability to get this right effectively made the game unplayable as I cannot progress?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the game, but you may be able to use an Autohotkey script if you're playing on pc.

Comment: I assume if it's like any other game, you won't be able to progress until you beat it (unless the Combo Chicken Lessons are optional).  There seem to be a few [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LVTkuZhuEQ) out there that you might be able to watch to get the combo down, and then keep practicing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this wiki](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/guacamelee/Combo_Chicken), Combo Chicken cannot be skipped (emphasis mine):

> Combo Chicken can be started as soon as you reach Santa Luchita, **but cannot be finished until Juan has learned all Special Moves.**

For what it's worth, this is widely considered an annoying part of the game, and fairly repetitive and difficult (so I wouldn't blame it entirely on a lack of fine motor skills).

However, I found [these](https://steamcommunity.com/app/214770/discussions/0/540736587285306626/) [threads](https://steamcommunity.com/app/214770/discussions/0/846960628549045819/) which make a couple of suggestions on how to beat it, which include:

- Pushing Poncho back against the wall - this should help with targeting him and landing the combos
- Taking your time - the buttons don't need to be pressed immediately, so taking some extra time to make sure you have the directions correct can help ensure the combo lands correctly

I also [found](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-67UL0pvjc) [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LVTkuZhuEQ) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvhgKt_3ynU) which may be of some help in figuring out exactly what the combo is, and providing some insight into how to land them correctly.

Based on my personal experience with Guacamelee, this part of the game is, erm, *challenging*. I fancy myself as having played a few fighting games in my day, but this part of the game definitely took some time. For me, I just kept practicing, and deliberately trying to push the correct buttons in the correct sequence (that was my main problem). So I would recommend beyond the advice from the sources above, just try to be really deliberate in your actions, take your time, and you should be able to pass it after a couple of tries!

Comment: Kept working at it, and finally managed to beat it last night. Those tips really helped!

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be skipped mainly due to the fact that it ties into the poncho'd out achievement/trophy. My best suggestion is to find some of the tutorial videos and see if it in any way can help you with your issue.